# How can this CNN be implemented?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I was reading the paper "Detection of Malicious Code Variants Based on Deep Learning" by Zhihua Cui et. al and stumbled upon a problem. The paper contains the following passage:

"*For  our  model,  we  designed  different  architectures  of  the CNN for malware images with different sizes. For the 24x24 inputs,  our  model  had  seven  layers,  including  five  hidden layers.  The  detailed  structure  was  as  follows:  C1:8*20*20, S2:8*10*10,  C3:16*8*8,   S4:16*4*4,  and  C5:80*1*1.  Each type  of  convolution  kernel  corresponded  to  a  type  of  feature map.  The  maps  per  layer  referred  to  the  number  of  feature maps  per  layer.  For  the  input  of  other  sizes,  as  the  size increased,  the  number  of  layers  increased  (e.g.,  double  size meant adding two layers).*"

So my CNN implementation for a 24x24 grayscale input image would be of the form:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 5, activation="relu", input_shape=(24,24,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(5, 4, activation="relu"))
```

But what is meant by "*double size meant adding two layers*"? How would an implementation of a 48x48 grayscale input image look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `model.summary()` to see the output shape after each layer, so for a `24x24x1` input you have:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d (Conv2D)              (None, 20, 20, 8)         208
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d (MaxPooling2D) (None, 10, 10, 8)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 8, 8, 2)           146
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 4, 4, 2)           0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 1, 5)           165
=================================================================
```

Notice that you end up with, essentially, 5 values, after the last convolution (i.e. the number of filters).

If you increase the input size to `48x48x1`, you'll get a `7x7x5` output:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 44, 44, 8)         208
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 22, 22, 8)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 20, 20, 2)         146
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 10, 10, 2)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 7, 7, 5)           165
=================================================================
```

I assume you want an output of `1x1x5`, as in the first example, so you need two add new layers that will reduce the height & width of the image down to `1x1`, for example:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(8, 5, activation="relu", input_shape=(48,48,1)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
# new layers
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(2))
# ---
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(5, 4, activation="relu"))
```

And you will get:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_21 (Conv2D)           (None, 44, 44, 8)         208
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_16 (MaxPooling (None, 22, 22, 8)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_22 (Conv2D)           (None, 20, 20, 2)         146
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_17 (MaxPooling (None, 10, 10, 2)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_23 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 2)           38
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_18 (MaxPooling (None, 4, 4, 2)           0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_24 (Conv2D)           (None, 1, 1, 5)           165
=================================================================
```

Notice that, in your example, only the pooling layer has `stride = 2`, so this is where the size halving occurs; [Conv2D layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/) has by default `strides=(1, 1)`.

---

#### References

- [Conv shape calculator](https://madebyollin.github.io/convnet-calculator/)
- [CNN layers (CS231n)](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#layers)